# I'm an administrator on my PC but when I try to install openpyxl in program files (x86) says I don't have write access

Tags: python, windows, permission-denied

Here's the error.  I'm have administrator rights on this machine.  I just need a simple way to install openpyxl

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-4028.write-test'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.5.0a1>python setup.py install
```

Comment: Did you open the commandline as administrator? https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/

Comment: Right click on `cmd.exe` (should be in your `C:\Windows\System32` directory) and select `Run as administrator` from the pop-up menu.

Comment: Is the file there? Can you modify/delete it?

Comment: marineau, thank you very much.  That solved my problem.  I'm very grateful.  Have a terrific day!!

Comment: thanks Hugh Bothwell that works for me. I did not I did not imagine that that was the error

Answer (score 0):

Try working in a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv
```

Then install things using `C:\path\to\venv\bin\pip` and execute using `c:\path\to\venv\bin\python`. HTH.